# Generic MVC Controller cannot provide delegate to EF FindBy function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics

I am wrapping up a generically-crafted SQL table editor for a configuration application, using Entity Framework, a Repository pattern, so on and so forth.  Probably a bit overkill on the layers.  In any case, I have a generic MVC controller (we'll call it `MyController<T>`) looking to send its calls to a generic service layer (`MyServices<T>`), where everything "of T" is some data model class representing a SQL table, directly.  Each and every data model class has an ident field called "Id", that is implemented from a base model (that itself, is implementing an interface).

Everything is very simple and smooth, except when I need to call the FindBy option on a data set, where i have to provide a delegate to search on something of a generic type.  I understand that the type constraints need to have an interface attached to it so that I can access that "Id" field in any type T, but doing so causes conflict with any controllers that explicitly implement the generic controller.  So:

Generic Service layer:

```
public abstract class MyServices<T> : IMyService<T> where T : class,  new()
{
    IMyRepository<T> _MyRepository;

    public MyServices(IMyRepository<T> MyRepository)
    {
        _MyRepository = MyRepository;
    }
    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
       return _MyRepository.FindBy(predicate);
    }
}
```

Generic Repository:

```
public partial class MyRepository<T> : IMyRepository<T> where T : class, new() 
{
     MyTablesEntities _entities = new MyTablesEntities();

     public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {

        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }
}
```

Generic Controller:

```
public class MyController<T> : Controller where T : class, new()
{
    private string ViewTitle = typeof(T).ToString();
    private readonly IMyServices<T> _MyServices = default(IMyServices<T>);

    public MyController() { }

    public MyController(IMyServices<T> mtt)
    {
        _MyServices = mtt;
    }

 public ActionResult Edit(int? id) 
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        T editItem = _MyServices.FindBy(c => **c.Id == id**).SingleOrDefault(); 

        if (editItem == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return PartialView(editItem);
    }
}
```

and a Controller using MyController:

```
 public class AccountsController : MTTablesController<Accounts>
{  }
```

Obviously, with this setup, the FindBy delegate clause cannot differentiate the type of T until runtime, so it fails to compile this way, giving:

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found

If, however, I add the interface (IMyTableEntity) that contains a property of 'Id' to the constraint of the generic controller:

```
public class MyController<T> : Controller where T : class, MyTables.DataAccess.Metadata.Base.IMyTableEntity, new()

public interface IMyTableEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I now get THIS error, over on the implementing Controller:

> The type 'MyTables.DataAccess.Account' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyController<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyTables.DataAccess.Account' to 'MyTables.DataAccess.Metadata.Base.IMyTableEntity'.

I am at an impasse here as both errors lead me back into trying the other way, neither of which are working.  I need the generic 'T' on the generic controller  to be smart enough to carry the Id field with it, without confusing the implementing controllers above it.

Comment: there are occasional misspellings or plurals left out of Class/Service/Controller names, due to sensitivity.  I do not have issues along those lines here...

Comment: Can you post your generic repository code?

Comment: added to the OP, with naming corrections added

Comment: Your class  'MyTables.DataAccess.Account' must implement `IMyTableEntity`

Answer (score 0):

trailmax may have found it...

> Your class 'MyTables.DataAccess.Account' must implement IMyTableEntity

My Data modelling is set up in this way:

1. EF base partial classes:

   ```
   public partial class Accounts  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Code { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Metadata models that contain data Annotations:

   ```
   public class AccountsMetadata : MyTables.DataAccess.Metadata.Base.MyTableEntity {
   [Key]
   [Required]
   [UniqueValidator]        
   public string Code { get; set; }

   [Display(Name="Description")]
   [StringLength(100)]
   public string Description { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. a bootstrap that ties them together

   ```
   [MetadataType(typeof(AccountsMetadata))]
     public partial class Accounts { }
   ```

what i needed to do was add the implementation of the interface to the bootstrap definitions for every partial, i.e.:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AccountsMetadata))]
public partial class Accounts : MyTables.DataAccess.Metadata.Base.IMyTableEntity { }
```

and then follow that up by setting the IMyTableEntity interface as a constraint on T in the Generic Controller, as i outlined above...